# Confirm passwords using ion-md-input

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-material

I tried using ui-validate to confirm passwords but it only works with regular input tags. Can someone please help me figure this out as i do not want to lose the ion-md-input styling. Thank You.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could be a little more specific. What have you tried, what error do you get etc.

Comment: i have tried ui-validate and various directives i found online which work with normal input tags but not ion-md-input